# Matlab - How to to fill an area in 3D space?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, scatter-plot

I wanted to fill a region in 3D space using some conditions.

Suppose there is a vector like this:

```matlab
x1 = 100;
y1 = 102;
z1 = 103;
P1 = [x1, y1, z1];
```

now I want to indicate the space for all possible values of `P2 = [x2, y2, z2];` such as:

```
x2 < x1;
y2 < y1;
z2 < z1;
x1 - x2 < y1 - y2;
y1 - y2 < z1 - z2;
|angle between P1 and P2| < pi/20
```

I don't think the [fill3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill3.html) function would work.

I have tried plotting all possible points, but it is very slow:

```matlab
r1 = 100;
g1 = 102;
b1 = 103;

P1 = [r1, g1, b1];

for r2 = 0:0.1:r1
    for g2 = 0:0.1:g1
        for b2=0:0.1:b1

            % calculate angle between two vectors
            P2 = [r2, g2, b2];
            a = abs(atan2(norm(cross(P1,P2)),dot(P1,P2)));
            
            % draw point if conditions are true
            if ((b1 - b2) < (g1 - g2)) && ((g1 - g2) <= (r1 - r2)) && (a < (pi/20)) 
                scatter3(r2,g2,b2,5,'g');
                hold on;
            end
            
        end
    end
end
```

How can I apply these conditions and fill the area in 3D space for all possible values of `P2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing each point with a separate call to `scatter3`. Instead, you should first perform the calculations and find the points, then plot them all at once:

```
r1 = 100; g1 = 102; b1 = 103;
P1 = [r1, g1, b1];
step = .5;
r = 0:step:r1;
g = 0:step:g1;
b = 0:step:b1;
[R, G, B] = meshgrid(r, g, b);
n = numel(R);
inside = false(size(R));
for ii= 1:n
    r2 = R(ii);
    g2 = G(ii);
    b2 = B(ii);
    
    % calculate angle between two vectors
    P2 = [r2, g2, b2];
    a = abs(atan2(norm(cross(P1,P2)),dot(P1,P2)));
    
    % draw point if conditions are true
    if ((b1 - b2) < (g1 - g2)) && ((g1 - g2) <= (r1 - r2)) && (a < (pi/20))
        inside(ii) = true;
    end
end
scatter3(R(inside), G(inside), B(inside), 5, 'g');
```

Also, if you are interested in illustrating the volume, you can call `convhull` to find convex hall of the found points:

```
k = convhull(R(inside), G(inside), B(inside));
trisurf(k,R(inside), G(inside), B(inside), 'facecolor', 'g', 'edgealpha', .1)
```

You can even simplify the convex hull:

```
k = convhull(R(inside), G(inside), B(inside),'Simplify',true);
```

[image]

**Edit: add transparency**

You can make your scatter plot transparent by setting its `'MarkerEdgeAlpha'` property. However, it may not change the outcome much, except for edges of the volume. That's because there are too many markers covering each other:

```
subplot 131
scatter3(R(inside), G(inside), B(inside), 5, 'r');
axis equal, title('solid')

subplot 132
scatter3(R(inside), G(inside), B(inside), 5, 'r', ...
    'markeredgealpha', 0.1);
axis equal, title('transparent')

subplot 133
scatter3(R(inside), G(inside), B(inside), 5, 'r', ...
    'markeredgealpha', 0.1);
axis equal, title('zoomed'), zoom(4)
```

[image]

You can also make the surf object transparent:

```
subplot 121
trisurf(k,R(inside), G(inside), B(inside), 'facecolor', 'g', ...
    'edgealpha', 0.1)
axis equal, title('solid')

subplot 122
trisurf(k,R(inside), G(inside), B(inside), 'facecolor', 'g', ...
    'facealpha', 0.3, 'edgealpha', .1)
axis equal, title('transparent')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. perfect solution

Comment: is there a way to add transparency to the surface? I tried using `set(h, 'MarkerEdgeAlpha', alpha, 'MarkerFaceAlpha', alpha);` where `h` is the scatter, but didn't make any difference.

Comment: I'm glad it helped @hadi jan. I edited may post to add the transparency.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The `facealpha` option works better.